# Iterate through every char in string stored in an array

Tags: c, string, iterator

I am really new to C and in my first half year at university. This is my first questio on StackOverflow.

My task is to program it so every string stored in numbers is being converted into a decimal, without changing anything outside the main function.

I am now trying for the past 4 hours to solve this problem, where I want to iterate trough every char in the string I am currently to then, based on there position in comparison to the length to convert it into a decimal.

My only question here is to someone help me to understand how I can get the string length without using `strlen()` due to the fact I can't add `#include <string.h>`

This is what I got so far (getting the length of the array to iterate through every index):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h> // Kompilieren mit -lm : gcc -Wall -std=c11 dateiname.c -lm

int main() {
    char* numbers[] = {
        "01001001",
        "00101010",
        "010100111001",
        "011111110100101010010111",
        "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
        "01011100110000001101"};
    
    // Add here..
    
    int length = sizeof(numbers);
    
    

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
        
         //how do i get the string size without strlen() D:
            
        }
        
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how `strlen` works, or in general, what determines the length of a string in C?

Comment: I think i know how strlen() works, but in this case i cant use it to determine the actual size of the current string

Comment: Note: `strlen()` signature is `size_t strlen(const char *s);`, yet `strlen()` is not needed to stop the `for` loop.  Just look for the _null character_.

Comment: `sizeof` returns the number of bytes needed to hold its argument, which is not what you want for `length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, strings are really just `char` arrays with a special terminator character to mark the end of the string.  So, say you have something like:

```
char *str = "hello";
```

This is essentially equivalent to this:

```
char str[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

Notice that `\0` character at the end of the array?  This is the special terminator character that C places at the end of strings.  Functions like `strlen()` pretty much iterate through the `char` array looking for the first occurrence of the `\0` character and then stopping.

So, you can make your own version of `strlen()`, say `my_strlen()` like this:

```
int my_strlen(char *str)
{
    /* Initialize len to 0 */
    int len = 0;
    
    /* Iterate through str, increment len, and stop when we reach '\0' */
    while(str[len] != '\0')
        len++;
    
    /* Return the len */
    return len;
}
```

Then within your `for` loop, you can just call this function.  Also, note that your calculation of the size of the `numbers` array:

```
int length = sizeof(numbers);
```

will not give you the number of elements in the array.  That code gives you the size (in bytes) or `numbers` which is an array of `char` pointers.  If you want to get the number of elements, you have to divide that size by the size (in bytes) of a single element (i.e., a `char` pointer).  So, something like this would work:

```
int length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
```

Your final code can look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h> // Kompilieren mit -lm : gcc -Wall -std=c11 dateiname.c -lm

int my_strlen(char *str) {
    /* Initialize len to 0 */
    int len = 0;
    
    /* Iterate through str, increment len, and stop when we reach '\0' */
    while(str[len] != '\0')
        len++;
    
    /* Return the len */
    return len;
}

int main() {
    char* numbers[] = {
        "01001001",
        "00101010",
        "010100111001",
        "011111110100101010010111",
        "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
        "01011100110000001101"};
    
    // Add here..
    
    // Notice the change here
    int length = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]);
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
        int str_len = my_strlen(numbers[i]);
        // Do what you need with str_len            
    }
        
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This project can be done without computing the length of the strings. How? In C, all strings are *nul-terminated* containing the *nul-character* `'\0'` (with ASCII value `0`) after the last character that makes up the string. When you need to iterate over a string, you just loop until the character values is `0` (e.g. the *nul-character*)

This is how all string function know when to stop reading characters. Since you have an *array-of-pointers* that contains your strings, you just need to loop over each pointer and for each pointer, loop over each character until the nul-character is found.

Putting it altogether, (and noting you don't need `math.h`), you can do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h> // Kompilieren mit -lm : gcc -Wall -std=c11 dateiname.c -lm

int main() {
    char* numbers[] = {
        "01001001",
        "00101010",
        "010100111001",
        "011111110100101010010111",
        "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
        "01011100110000001101"};
    
    int nnumbers = sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers;    /* no. of elements */
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nnumbers; i++) {
        long long unsigned number = 0;
        /* you don't care about the length, strings are nul-terminated,
         * just loop until \0 is found.
         */
        for (int j = 0; numbers[i][j]; j++) {
            number <<= 1;                               /* shift left */
            number += numbers[i][j] == '1' ? 1 : 0;     /* add bit */
        }
        
        printf ("%s = %llu\n", numbers[i], number);     /* output result */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you must use a 64-bit type to hold the converted values as `"1010110011010101111101111010101110110"` requires a minimum of `38` bits to represent)

**Example Use/Output**

Simple example output converting each string to a numeric value:

```
$ ./bin/binstr2num
01001001 = 73
00101010 = 42
010100111001 = 1337
011111110100101010010111 = 8342167
0001010110011010101111101111010101110110 = 92790519158
01011100110000001101 = 379917
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.  IMO, a simple, reasonable way to implement `strlen` is:

```
size_t string_length(const char *s)  { return strchr(s, '\0') - s; }
```

but if you're not allowed to use `strlen` then you're probably not allowed to use `strchr` either.  So you just have to count.  The most idiomatic way to do that is probably a bit obscure for a complete beginner, so here is a more verbose method.

Note that your computation of the number of elements in the array is invalid, and has been corrected below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
length(const char *s)
{
        int len = 0;
        while( *s++ ){
                len += 1;
        }
        return len;
}

int
main(void)
{
        char *numbers[] = {
                "01001001",
                "00101010",
                "010100111001",
                "011111110100101010010111",
                "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
                "01011100110000001101"
        };
        int count = sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers; /* Number of entries */

        for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ){
                printf(" length of %s is %d\n", numbers[i], length(numbers[i]));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

It's pretty subjective, but IMO a more idiomatic way to write this is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
length(const char *e)
{
        const char *s = e;
        while( *e++ )
                ;
        return e - s - 1;
}

int
main(void)
{
        char *numbers[] = {
                "01001001",
                "00101010",
                "010100111001",
                "011111110100101010010111",
                "0001010110011010101111101111010101110110",
                "01011100110000001101"
        };
        char **e = numbers + sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers;
        for( char **t = numbers; t < e; t++ ){
                printf(" length of %s is %d\n", *t, length(*t));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    char arr[20]="Hello";
    int count=0;
   
    while(arr[count]!='\0'){
        count++;
    }
    printf("%d",count);

    return 0;
}
```

Look at this small code, you will understand. In C a string ended with a NULL character. We can use that advantage.